# Set multiple base classes

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I am using my MainActivity.cs as a FragmentActivity now, but I also need it to be a AppCompatActivity. Now when I try this:

```
public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity, AppCompatActivity
```

It gives the error:

> Class 'MainActivity' cannot have multiple base classes:
>   'FragmentActivity' and 'AppCompatActivity'

But I need both, so how can I fix this?

Comment: C# does not support multiple inheritance. Use composition maybe.

Comment: Composition is important because inheritance is not the ideal way to add functionality to a class. If a class needs to be able to do something that isn't part of its own purpose, then it should depend on another class to do that instead of inheriting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C# does not support multiple base classes, but allows to implement multiple interfaces. And composition is legal too.

Do it like this:

```
class A
{
    public void DoAStuff() { }
}

class B
{
    public void DoBStuff() { }
}

class C
{
    private readonly A a;
    private readonly B b;

    public C(A a, B b) => (this.a, this.b) = (a, b);

    public void DoAStuff() => a.DoAStuff();

    public void DoBStuff() => b.DoBStuff();

    public static implicit operator A(C c) => c.a;

    public static implicit operator B(C c) => c.b;
}
```

Note, you will be able to cast `C` to `A` and `B` implicitly like

```
C c = new C(new A(), new B());
c.DoAStuff();
c.DoBStuff();
A a = c;
a.DoAStuff();
B b = c;
b.DoBStuff();
```

but

```
new[] { new C(new A(), new B()) }.Cast<B>().ToArray()
```

will throw `System.InvalidCastException`.

Use

```
new[] { new C(new A(), new B()) }.Select(i => (B)i).ToArray();
```

If `FragmentActivity` and `AppCompatActivity` implement interfaces do it like this:

```
interface IA
{
    void DoAStuff();
}

class A : IA
{
    public void DoAStuff() { }
}

interface IB
{
    void DoBStuff();
}

class B : IB
{
    public void DoBStuff() { }
}

class C : IA, IB
{
    private readonly IA a;
    private readonly IB b;

    public C(IA a, IB b) => (this.a, this.b) = (a, b);

    public void DoAStuff() => a.DoAStuff();

    public void DoBStuff() => b.DoBStuff();
}
```

In this case any casting will work fine.